# When storing Java 8 LocalTime, which data type should I use in an Oracle Database?

Tags: java, oracle, java-time

In most other databases, we'd use a TIME datatype, but it seems like Oracle doesn't have it.

I've tried VARCHAR (it ends up getting stored as January 1970) and a TIMESTAMP (stored as January 1970 with the correct time, but it doesn't allow retrieval again).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the data-types:

- `TIMESTAMP` with a constant year, month and day (you can put a check constraint on the column to enforce that only the time component should change);
- `DATE` with a constant year, month and day (if you are not worried about fractional seconds; and, again, you can use a check constraint);
- `INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND`; or
- `VARCHAR2` as a formatted time string.

Whatever you use you are going to need to convert it from a Java `LocalTime` object to the appropriate data-type before persisting it in the data-base and then reverse the conversion when you retrieve it.

Comment: Ah so what you're saying is that there's no directly corresponding data type and I'll need some sort of converter in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has two basic data types to deal with date/time.  Both are binary structures with no formatting as you would think of it.  A DATE contains both date and time, down to the second:

- 4 digit year
- month
- day of month
- hour - on a 24-hour clock
- minute
- second

The TIMESTAMP type is like the DATE, but resolves time down to the nano-second. It also has variations for dealing with timezones.

In both DATE and TIMESTAMP, the time for midnight is 00:00:00  (or 00:00:00.000000 for TIMESTAMP).

Trying to store a date or timestamp in any kind of string type, like VARCHAR2, is a *HUGE* design flaw.  If you are presented with a date/time that is actually just a character string, you need to convert it with either the DATE or TIMESTAMP literals as shown by @SanjeevRM, or using the TO_DATE or TO_TIMESTAMP functions.  When you need to format a DATE or a TIMESTAMP into a character string for human consumption, you do that with the TO_CHAR function.